# cannot access localhost:8000 after running docker swarm getting-started

Tags: docker-swarm

I follow the tutorial https://docs.docker.com/get-started/swarm-deploy/
every run normally, when running `docker service ls` I have

```
u9m7tz0ge3bp   demo_bb-app   replicated   1/1        getting-started:latest   *:8000->3000/tcp
```

But I just cannot access it with `localhost:8000`.
I try inspect the only docker container running named `getting-started:latest`, and getting this

```
{
  "Id": "56b090b8dfeaf83ebde811edad6c964d4ef4a25cd863a3c0b746e6a2476a26d4",
  "Created": "2023-09-29T06:36:47.045440539Z",
  "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
  "Args": [
    "node",
    "src/index.js"
  ],
  "State": {
    "Status": "running",
    "Running": true,
    "Paused": false,
    "Restarting": false,
    "OOMKilled": false,
    "Dead": false,
    "Pid": 68351,
    "ExitCode": 0,
    "Error": "",
    "StartedAt": "2023-09-29T06:36:47.625880494Z",
    "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "Image": "sha256:d1831fc1549a552d64c871d0d1ae284c2db46cd5bc2f0a8b5a3c0b449d4831f5",
  "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/56b090b8dfeaf83ebde811edad6c964d4ef4a25cd863a3c0b746e6a2476a26d4/resolv.conf",
  "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/56b090b8dfeaf83ebde811edad6c964d4ef4a25cd863a3c0b746e6a2476a26d4/hostname",
  "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/56b090b8dfeaf83ebde811edad6c964d4ef4a25cd863a3c0b746e6a2476a26d4/hosts",
  "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/56b090b8dfeaf83ebde811edad6c964d4ef4a25cd863a3c0b746e6a2476a26d4/56b090b8dfeaf83ebde811edad6c964d4ef4a25cd863a3c0b746e6a2476a26d4-json.log",
  "Name": "/demo_bb-app.1.7y6b1x5xopvgm6dc6a7sg1ilf",
  "RestartCount": 0,
  "Driver": "overlay2",
  "Platform": "linux",
  "MountLabel": "",
  "ProcessLabel": "",
  "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
  "ExecIDs": null,
  "HostConfig": {
    "Binds": null,
    "ContainerIDFile": "",
    "LogConfig": {
      "Type": "json-file",
      "Config": {}
    },
    "NetworkMode": "default",
    "PortBindings": {},
    "RestartPolicy": {
      "Name": "",
      "MaximumRetryCount": 0
    },
    "AutoRemove": false,
    "VolumeDriver": "",
    "VolumesFrom": null,
    "ConsoleSize": [
      0,
      0
    ],
    "CapAdd": null,
    "CapDrop": null,
    "CgroupnsMode": "private",
    "Dns": null,
    "DnsOptions": null,
    "DnsSearch": null,
    "ExtraHosts": null,
    "GroupAdd": null,
    "IpcMode": "private",
    "Cgroup": "",
    "Links": null,
    "OomScoreAdj": 0,
    "PidMode": "",
    "Privileged": false,
    "PublishAllPorts": false,
    "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
    "SecurityOpt": null,
    "UTSMode": "",
    "UsernsMode": "",
    "ShmSize": 67108864,
    "Runtime": "runc",
    "Isolation": "default",
    "CpuShares": 0,
    "Memory": 0,
    "NanoCpus": 0,
    "CgroupParent": "",
    "BlkioWeight": 0,
    "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
    "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
    "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
    "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
    "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
    "CpuPeriod": 0,
    "CpuQuota": 0,
    "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
    "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
    "CpusetCpus": "",
    "CpusetMems": "",
    "Devices": null,
    "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
    "DeviceRequests": null,
    "MemoryReservation": 0,
    "MemorySwap": 0,
    "MemorySwappiness": null,
    "OomKillDisable": null,
    "PidsLimit": null,
    "Ulimits": [],
    "CpuCount": 0,
    "CpuPercent": 0,
    "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
    "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
    "MaskedPaths": [
      "/proc/asound",
      "/proc/acpi",
      "/proc/kcore",
      "/proc/keys",
      "/proc/latency_stats",
      "/proc/timer_list",
      "/proc/timer_stats",
      "/proc/sched_debug",
      "/proc/scsi",
      "/sys/firmware"
    ],
    "ReadonlyPaths": [
      "/proc/bus",
      "/proc/fs",
      "/proc/irq",
      "/proc/sys",
      "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
    ]
  },
  "GraphDriver": {
    "Data": {
      "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3d1be60acac43d9d540b9e1bb2fa1f0104007b11a176590bb5adada02f911b07-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0rukpuqjg4uhvybhs4pj82g86/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/hfd2mcm093l1dgr1tvxg4o8l4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/wd03ak5hb4l9gkpgcvlo8e5sv/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/59483829ba90a9b6b8cbef5c600f49a4ba49c892e18401c36ad135555d9d9c59/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6bcabb013167abbb819542b20152ffb3005310340b91f64533e0f31aedfbe1db/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7de3853a77c989e642e2090b2b359f703bebb7e07714fa7daa4dc2f5fe5fbc7a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4b4ecdfe85a9a2e821b383552424e268d9f1b117c8fec203f25423bf385958f1/diff",
      "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3d1be60acac43d9d540b9e1bb2fa1f0104007b11a176590bb5adada02f911b07/merged",
      "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3d1be60acac43d9d540b9e1bb2fa1f0104007b11a176590bb5adada02f911b07/diff",
      "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3d1be60acac43d9d540b9e1bb2fa1f0104007b11a176590bb5adada02f911b07/work"
    },
    "Name": "overlay2"
  },
  "Mounts": [],
  "Config": {
    "Hostname": "56b090b8dfea",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "ExposedPorts": {
      "3000/tcp": {}
    },
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
      "NODE_VERSION=18.18.0",
      "YARN_VERSION=1.22.19"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "node",
      "src/index.js"
    ],
    "Image": "getting-started:latest",
    "Volumes": null,
    "WorkingDir": "/app",
    "Entrypoint": [
      "docker-entrypoint.sh"
    ],
    "OnBuild": null,
    "Labels": {
      "com.docker.stack.namespace": "demo",
      "com.docker.swarm.node.id": "mwmthz33ssx2mrthslw4lhcns",
      "com.docker.swarm.service.id": "u9m7tz0ge3bpojgyp266lkst4",
      "com.docker.swarm.service.name": "demo_bb-app",
      "com.docker.swarm.task": "",
      "com.docker.swarm.task.id": "7y6b1x5xopvgm6dc6a7sg1ilf",
      "com.docker.swarm.task.name": "demo_bb-app.1.7y6b1x5xopvgm6dc6a7sg1ilf"
    }
  },
  "NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "5db304fdb114c5c5ca2758fd164c31030fee1bbc82d0aaae9e05bc66f56d1de7",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {
      "3000/tcp": null
    },
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/5db304fdb114",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "",
    "Gateway": "",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "",
    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "MacAddress": "",
    "Networks": {
      "demo_default": {
        "IPAMConfig": {
          "IPv4Address": "10.0.3.3"
        },
        "Links": null,
        "Aliases": [
          "56b090b8dfea"
        ],
        "NetworkID": "zrvs2m2wu2py0zikftsyotbrq",
        "EndpointID": "4c39508939c34ed7ef36c9c541cf39bc4db742d2ee816d67bc9e166be0625e3d",
        "Gateway": "",
        "IPAddress": "10.0.3.3",
        "IPPrefixLen": 24,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:03:03",
        "DriverOpts": null
      },
      "ingress": {
        "IPAMConfig": {
          "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.9"
        },
        "Links": null,
        "Aliases": [
          "56b090b8dfea"
        ],
        "NetworkID": "v68qo0sr2mzz98p8yilhz5l4v",
        "EndpointID": "f91aba4c278c60cefbcd88d16641c57aa2bb6b74a3204dfd87c33d745783ef05",
        "Gateway": "",
        "IPAddress": "10.0.0.9",
        "IPPrefixLen": 24,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:09",
        "DriverOpts": null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

running `docker ps` gives me this

```
56b090b8dfea   getting-started:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 seconds ago   Up 18 seconds   3000/tcp   demo_bb-app.1.7y6b1x5xopvgm6dc6a7sg1ilf
```

I have no idea why this happens and it happens on both of my two computers.

**Updated:**
I made a mistake in the port. When I failed to connect to port 8000, I did try change it to 8080, but still failed. I updated the port in the post.

Running `docker service inspect` give me this

```
[
    {
        "ID": "u9m7tz0ge3bpojgyp266lkst4",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 64
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2023-09-29T06:36:42.861278482Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2023-09-29T06:36:42.868695021Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "demo_bb-app",
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.stack.image": "getting-started",
                "com.docker.stack.namespace": "demo"
            },
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "getting-started:latest",
                    "Labels": {
                        "com.docker.stack.namespace": "demo"
                    },
                    "Privileges": {
                        "CredentialSpec": null,
                        "SELinuxContext": null
                    },
                    "StopGracePeriod": 10000000000,
                    "DNSConfig": {},
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {},
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "any",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                },
                "Placement": {},
                "Networks": [
                    {
                        "Target": "zrvs2m2wu2py0zikftsyotbrq",
                        "Aliases": [
                            "bb-app"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "RollbackConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 3000,
                        "PublishedPort": 8000,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 3000,
                        "PublishedPort": 8000,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Ports": [
                {
                    "Protocol": "tcp",
                    "TargetPort": 3000,
                    "PublishedPort": 8000,
                    "PublishMode": "ingress"
                }
            ],
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "v68qo0sr2mzz98p8yilhz5l4v",
                    "Addr": "10.0.0.8/24"
                },
                {
                    "NetworkID": "zrvs2m2wu2py0zikftsyotbrq",
                    "Addr": "10.0.3.2/24"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

**Updated:**
I use `docker network inspect ingress`
then I can use the `[0].Peers.IP` instead of `localhost` to access the app.

```
[
    {
        "Name": "demo_default",
        "Id": "lr8ynlnbrlbwmtp3cx5jo8ebg",
        "Created": "2023-09-29T15:57:26.523369862+07:00",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.4.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.4.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "5b2a061f0c2f07f186e72d0cf29f63a3861ea7eee52ce471c33f3d936fffe641": {
                "Name": "demo_bb-app.1.kd3t1zgd2w6w4ud8m27hwlnpo",
                "EndpointID": "b4da98e041e39ea30305248582c17575f2699ce5e6133552084a4a26cea29f95",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:04:03",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.4.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-demo_default": {
                "Name": "demo_default-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "3f699fa011cd450c5fd83244f2e465aca9bff68553bc67fa02ded832f5df55c8",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:04:04",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.4.4/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4100"
        },
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.stack.namespace": "demo"
        },
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "f5cd82c01e13",
                "IP": "192.168.27.203"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Please check the above as you are saying the service started with a mapped port `8080` and you try to access it on `8000`...

Comment: 3000/tcp looks like your service is running on a different port than you expected. With docker you have a container localhost and a host localhost, stuff running in the container have to be mapped to the host, otherwise it won't be accessible. Also I use strict firewalling and need to explicitly allow access to the lo device (edit I didn't see you map 8080 to 3000,  because it is not visible until I scroll to the end)

Comment: @Zeitounator pardon me for my mistake. I did try changing to port 8080 to see there is any different after failing to access port 8000. I updated the post

Comment: @sleepyhead pardon me for my mistake. I did try changing to port 8080 to see there is any different after failing to access port 8000. I updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the command `docker swarm init --advertise-addr 127.0.0.1`, then The [0].Peers.IP change to `127.0.0.1`. Then I can access the service on `http://127.0.0.1:8000`